# Table of contents in book

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am preparing for my thesis and I have some problems on the tableofcontents. My text source is the following

```
  \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}   
   ..................
 ...............................

  \include{{./Chapter1/chapter1}}

  \thispagestyle{empty}


 \thispagestyle{empty}    \bibliographystyle{alpha}

  \bibliography{refs.bib}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

 \include{{./Samenvatting/Samenvatting}}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Samenvatting} 

 \thispagestyle{empty}    \include{{./Samenvatting/summary}}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary} 

 \thispagestyle{empty}    \include{{./Samenvatting/Sommario}}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sommario}

  \thispagestyle{empty}    \include{{./ack/ack}} 

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}

  \thispagestyle{empty}    \include{{./CV/CV}} 

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae}

 \thispagestyle{empty}
```

However, in the table of contents, there are some problems :

1. the last item (CV in my tex) does not appear.
2. The page number of later sections : from Bibliography to the end, are wrong. They match with the number in the total text, but do not match with the number of their pages.

How could I fix this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Instead of using the quote markup button, use the code markup button (labeled `{}`) to highlight code. This indents blocks by four spaces, or encloses inline code in backticks (`\``).

Comment: 1. What type of file is your CV? In any case, you might be better off importing it with the `pgfpages` package. 2. The blank lines between each `\include` and `\addcontentsline` may be the source of the problem; try removing any blank space between each pair of those commands.

Comment: Additionally to Jubobs comment, your placement of `\addcontentsline` is after the included files, so the current page number at that point is the final page of the that file.  The correct position for the command would be at the point when the title in the included file is printed.  We would need to see one of those included files to suggest how to fix that.

Comment: @user28514 Please edit your question to show us the contents of one of these included files.  Otherwise we are just guessing in the dark.

Comment: Whilst guessing, problem 1 might be that your CV file ends with an `\end{document}` command so the latex processing stops at that point and does not see your final `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann : Thanks for your comment. However, How should I fix it?

Comment: The simplest solution is deleting `\end{document}` from the CV.  However, still guessing, if your CV is a separately compilable file, which you wish to preserve, then try the advice at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multidoc

Answer (score 1):

> the last item (CV in my tex) does not appear.

You should use *real* chapters in your tex files. Then there is no need to use `\addcontentsline`.

If that is no option you might define the following function:

```
\newcommand{\phantomeintrag}[2]{%
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{#2}
}
```

And then simply call (before you include the files!):

```
\phantomeintrag{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae}
```

> The page number of later sections : from Bibliography to the end, are wrong. They match with the number in the total text, but do not match with the number of their pages.

Not sure if I understand this correctly: Do you want that the page number starts at 1 for *each* included file?
Whatever - you can restart the page numbering using `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. Furthermore the counter can be set manually to any number at any time using the `\setcounter{page}{123}` command, where `123` is the new page number you’d like. Note that this can result in duplicate page numbers.

Comment: Thank DL6ER for your help. However, the first problem still remains.
For the second problem, I mean that, for example, the page number of Summary is 123, but it's shown 124 in the table of contents.

Comment: Then there is no other choice than to let us have a look in your file(s).

Comment: It works after I changed those items to, for example, :
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Curriculum Vitae}
\include{{./CV/CV}}
\thispagestyle{empty}